# Adding a TXT DNS record to a VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, txt-record

I have a VPS registered at [strato.com](http://www.strato.com) and I want to connect it to a google apps package.
Google apps needs to verify my ownership of the domain and wants me to add a specific TXT record to the DNS.

Unfortunately, this is not possible through strato config websites (only A and MX records are modifiable), so my question is: is it possible to add a TXT record on the VPS itself?

I'm not that experienced with DNS, so forgive me if it's rather stupid question.
Server configuration:

- Ubuntu 10.04
- Plesk 10
- BIND 9.7.0-P1

If you need more info, please ask.
I know I could use the other verify-options with google apps (like adding a html page), but I think this option is the most elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TXT record is a record directly on the DNS zone, so it needs to be managed there.  There isn't a workaround to have it handled elsewhere.

So your two options are either A) see if strato has a way to allow you to modify your TXT record or B) use another DNS provider for DNS (e.g. dyndns.com) which does support modifying TXT records.

Comment: In Plesk I can add a subscription for my domain name and edit it's DNS, but this has nothing to do with the 'real' DNS zone?

Comment: Plesk would be setup to point to the real DNS zone.  Plesk is working with your web server in one location, and your DNS zone in another location.  So any edits performed with Plesk really are editing the DNS zone.

Comment: Thanks so far, I really need to learn how to use Plesk... can't tell more than "it doesn't work" right now

Comment: I haven't used Plesk really so I can't speak into their features, but are you saying that Plesk doesn't allow the TXT editing, or that Plesk does allow the TXT editing but it doesn't seem to do anything?  Check out week 2 and week 3 of my Web Pro series.  You may find it helpful on this topic: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/tags/Web+Pro+Series/default.aspx?PageIndex=2

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. I can edit DNS records in Plesk (including TXT), but they don't do anything. If I change MX records at the strato config, they won't change in Plesk either (but show up in nslookup), so it seems they have no link with each other.

Comment: It sounds like Plesk is pointing to a non-authoritative dns zone that isn't used.  It's being saved into the abyss.  Plesk needs to point to the real strato zone for it to work.  I would use dyndns instead, or see if strato will manually update your TXT record for you if you tell them what the value should be.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. So I guess it's not possible to 'delegate' the dns to my VPS (so the server acts as authoritative DNS) through an A record, right?

Comment: Not easily.  Strato can delegate a 3rd level domain to you (i.e. city.yourdomain.com but to have the whole zone delegated you would need to do that right up at the registrar level.  But that involves setting up glue records and at least a pair of DNS servers.  That's overkill for one zone.  I bet that Strato will update a TXT record manually for you though.  It's not something that needs to be updated often.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Scott. I decided to move to another registrar, which does support proper DNS record editing. The easiest solution I guess.

Comment: Sometimes an alternate path works better than trying to create a path in front of you.  Sounds like that's the case for your situation.  Glad you got a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to switch to a more, lets say complete, DNS provider and registrar.

If the only records you can add are A and MX, that means you cant even add SPF records.
Witch will be a pain if you are using Google Apps (gmail).

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you to consider down the road is to transfer your domain to a better Registrar. Ie: GoDaddy, etc.

All of the major ones allow you to edit the DNS zone file which would give you the access to add additional records (TXT, MX, etc.) as needed.

You could also ask your host to create the records for you in the future if you choose to keep your domain & hosting at the same company.